# Wrong React useRef hook behavior with event listener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, use-effect

I'm confused about the useRef behavior.

1. setState on Parent element
2. render Children
3. Listen only once, but invoke callback twice. (in Children)

```
  if (ref.current) {
    console.log("listen");
    ref.current.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      console.log("xxxx click");
      // setCount(count + 1);
    });
  }
```

[image]

But It works fine, when I use useEffect instead.
Listen once, invoke callback once.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) return;
    console.log('listen');
    ref.current.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      console.log("xxx click");
      // setCount(count + 1);
    });
  }, [ref]);
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-platform-v4ugq?file=/src/comp.jsx

Answer (score 0):

This is because your app is wrapped in strict mode, and in strict mode the `setstate` will render twice,  try removing the strict mode in index.js, this solve the issue

[For more info](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-390206425)

[image]